# this in different types of callbacks?

Tags: javascript

We know that we have to preserve the value of `this` in callbacks in order to execute them with appropriate context. For example:

```
someArr.forEach(function(el) { console.log(this); });
```

Here `this` will be referring to window or undefined when we use `use strict`.

But when we are adding an event for example:

```
someBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        console.log(this); 
});
```

Here `this` refers to the button which is clicked. How come in this callback we dont have to bind any this while in former case we have to bind it explicitly.
I can be wrong so please clarify my doubt.

Comment: `this` in your `click` callback is not the same `this` as the `this` in the context where you attach the event handler (i.e. here: `this && someBtn.addEventHandler`). It's a different `this`. It's being changed. If you bound it, `this` inside the event handler would *not* refer to the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `this` [depends on how the function is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work).

When you pass the function to `addEventListener` or to `forEach` then you are setting things up for *code written by other people* to call it.

That code will call the function in different ways depending on the intentions of the people who wrote it.

Comment: But i dont get that in above cases which i have put in question....why in case of addEventListener we have the element's reference in the callback without even binding it to the callback??

Comment: @JotWaraich — Because whomever designed the `addEventListener` API thought that would be useful

Comment: @Jot Because the event handler is going to be called with `this` set to the element on which the event happened. `addEventListener` takes care of that.

Comment: So we can say that it also depends on the type of callback what it would have as `this` inside

Comment: No. It depends on the code that calls the callback.

Comment: Now i get it. So there is a different code which runs the forEach callback and different code which runs the addEventListener callback this time setting the value of `this` in the way